# Остановить отправку форму по клику на Submit

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка сабмита формы:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="ProfileEditor.saveWork(this)" value="Сохранить">
```

а так же ее обработчик:

```
saveWork: function(btn){
        alert('dd');
        return false;
    },
```

При клике должным образом выводится алерт, но затем сабмитится стандартно форма.
Стало быть return false не влияет. Что можно предпринять?

Comment: и ещё разок
# делать onclick в разметке - очень плохая практика. особенно когда используете jQuery.

буду постить пока не поймете. так бы сделали e.preventDefault() и всё.

Comment: но ладно, я сегодня добрый

> onclick="**return** ProfileEditor.saveWork(this)"

Comment: @eicto, там уже нет комментов. Если мы говорим о кроссбраузерности, то в `attachEvent` `this` будет `window`, также отсутствует currentTarget, в отличии от onclick. Глобальные переменные — это не аргумент, тогда можно каждый ваш ответ говорить, что у вас обращение к $/jQuery, ведь они глобальные объекты. Через onclick удобно передавать опции, при декларативном подходе (это удобнее чем data-*, которые теряют типизацию). 

Вот ещё пример `<img src="/fail.png" onerror="this.src = '/placeholder.png';"/>`. Честно не понимаю, почему вы так в штыки приняли мой ответ.

Comment: **Оффтоп** холивар плавно переехал в новую тему ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/e5w3cNG.gif

Comment: @Deonis, Всё же это не холивар, я же не настаиваю, что нужно писать через onXXXX, просто навешивание ярлыков «это плохо»,  не приносит никому пользы. Такая же история с new Function/eval, «зло и точка», хотя это очень важный и главное нужный инструмент, без которого невозможны многие вещи, без которых не может обойтись современный разработчик. Конечно не умелых руках это всё может кончится плохо, но и  при использовании любого высокоуровнего framework'а можно прострелить себе колено.

Comment: ну про attachEvent можно забыть уже давно, кроме того, кто мешает Element.onclick= использовать в таком случае ? attachEvent мертворожденное как и большинство собственных мелкомягких  задумок. 

jQuery как минимум библиотека она одна и известно что делает, а вот объявлять хэндлеры в global scope не нужно. 

в штыки принял очень просто - вы в теме плаваете и сбиваете новичков с нормальных путей.  global scope это не window например, да будет вам известно.

Comment: Я же уже сто раз повторил почему мне не без разницы, потому что вот он вас послушает и дальше свой ужас будет городить и мучиться, вы не боитесь что это вам это при следующем рождении припомнится ? (на самом деле еще в этом, коллеги которые массово будут задавать перехватчики в разметке уже поднимаются по лестнице в ваш офис, они еще будут использовать global и goto, eval и прочее, и аргументы у них будут такими же как у вас, потому что вы сами их научили.

Comment: ну и так, для справки мне ни разу в жизни не было необходимо вешать события напрямую в разметке (ангуляр не считаем - я уже сказал, у него не в глобальной области видимости дело происходит и не в глобальном контексте, он как раз лишен этих недостатков)

Comment: Нет, не боюсь :] Даже уверен, что они буду на моей стороне, с той или иной оговоркой. Я только пытался показать, что подход существует и на каких основаниях. Не больше. Моей задачею не была пропаганда повсеместного использования или ещё что-то в этом духе. Но... видно я «плаваю в теме», стыд и позор мне. Итого тему можно закрыть, я сливаюсь, у меня больше нет доводов, чтобы объяснить, почему использовать onclick для решения задачи не есть абсолютное зло.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<form action="/#" method="post" onsubmit="alert('submit!');return false">
    <input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть вероятность, что имеются другие обработчики,  слушатели прикрепленные к данному событию или элементу, которые отправляют данные с формы. Поэтому могу предложить такой вариант кода:

```
// отменяет событие отправки данных с формы
event.preventDefault(); 

// останавливает цепочку вызова событий для следующих слушателей
event.stopImmediatePropagation();

// проверим, вызвано ли событие preventDefault
if(!event.isDefaultPrevented()){
    // предотвратим действие по умолчанию (событие отправки с формы)
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Да, необходимо добавить `event` в качестве параметра в метод. Немного ссылок для ознакомления с описанием вызываемых методов и свойств:

- [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- [`Event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)
- [`Event.returnValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue)
- [`Event.defaultPrevented`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented)